# How to run an electron app on docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, electron, dockerfile

I've created a fork of a repository hosting an electron app which is a chat client: https://github.com/Serkan-devel/BetterDiscordApp-docker.

What I'm trying to do is to create a docker container with a GUI hooked to the own screen like at https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/ .

The dockerfile I've created goes like:

```
FROM node:slim

COPY . /usr/scr/app

#RUN rm bdstart.sh

RUN npm install --save-dev electron

RUN npm install

#ENV FRESHINSTALL=true

CMD ["/usr/scr/app/start.sh"]
```

The start.sh file goes like:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron ./src
```

After building the docker image and execute it with

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/snd dixord
```

I get the error code:

```
standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

although I made the file executable and used the right amd64 architecture.

Has anyone figured it out how to make electron GUI's naitively over docker work?

Comment: this is your `start.sh` or you just copy and paste the problematic line? because maybe you are missing `#!/bin/sh` - first line in shell script

Comment: Then I get `/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: On which OS are you building this image?

Comment: It's lubuntu 16.04

Comment: try `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0` or run start.sh with `root` user

Comment: the default user in docker is root

Comment: I added answer with detail how i was able to replicate your problem, I hope it will help you

Answer (score 8):

I will try to help you here in this answer - too long for comment.

I tried your Docker file on my Win10 and with the same problems.
But I figured it out by adding required packages and successfully created docker image.
Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM node:slim

COPY . /usr/scr/app

#RUN rm bdstart.sh
RUN apt-get update

# I think you need to install following 
RUN apt-get -y install libgtkextra-dev libgconf2-dev libnss3 libasound2 libxtst-dev libxss1
RUN npm install --save-dev electron

RUN npm install

CMD ["/usr/scr/app/start.sh"]
```

and here is your `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
./node_modules/.bin/electron ./src
```

Actually I don't have access to your files and so on, but with this DockerFile was able to create docker image without problems. I also went inside docker container and check whether is possible to run electron - *worked*.

If you want to go into container, you just need to build docker image. I have done it by (simplest way) following command *(**open** console **where Dockerfile is located** and run)*:

```
docker build -t test-image .
```

After Successfully build of image you can run container. If any problems I recommend you to run container with `bash` entrypoint and debug what fails - bash will open in the same console where you type following script)

```
docker run -it test-image bash
```

Comment: I've implemented your changes, re-build the image and running it how I ran it before, I then get as error `No protocol specified`. When running it in with bash (how you told) and executing the `start.sh`-file I then get `./start.sh: 4: ./start.sh: ./node_modules/.bin/electron: not found` as error. But did a window pop up when you successfully ran it?

Answer (score 3):

I've found this question useful, finally I've came up with this article to make it even easier:

https://medium.com/@calbertts/developing-electron-apps-in-macos-afd21b4a59e3#.avdge04d6

Hope, you find it useful too.

Comment: I read your article (cool stuff!), I saw you are using your own docker image called "calbertts/node-gtk", I was wondering what node docker image you used as base for this gtk image? I'm trying to see if I could get the same result without using Nut. I could use you docker image but I would like to know what it contains.

Comment: I just updated the hub repo (https://hub.docker.com/r/calbertts/node-gtk) where you can check it out.