# Web Runtime alternatives to Electron/nw.js for Centos 6?

Tags: reactjs, javafx, electron, node-webkit, nwjs

I know my title sounds crazy, as right now the popular practice is to use something like [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) or [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) for desktop applications written using web stack technologies, but here's why I'm searching for [alternative desktop web runtime solutions](https://github.com/flexxui/flexx/wiki/Overview-of-web-runtimes):

- I need to minimize the maintenance of both a desktop app and web app that both behave identically, ideally by consolidating the code as much as possible into a single repository.
- *BUT* the desktop app can't run using chromium-backed Electron or nw.js because it absolutely must run on Centos 6, which isn't officially supported by either (and I've sufficiently [beaten my head against the wall](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/6718) trying).

So, to minimize code paths and maximize compatibility, my options appear to be:

1. Wait 2.5 years for Centos 6 maintenance updates EOL (hopefully forcing customer migration)
2. Give up and deal with maintaining both a java GUI and web app as separate code entirely.
3. Re-purpose my web server for local desktop execution, so that it serves the same HTML/CSS/javascript but for access on localhost in whatever browser locally installed.
4. Use JavaFX and reuse (at least some of?) my javascript/css code inside a webview GUI element.

Has anyone else tried to bridge this gap to consolidate desktop apps and web apps when unfortunately Electron/nw.js aren't viable? Or does the simplification I'm searching for simply not exist?

Comment: Can you run Electron in a Docker container on your Centos machine?  That might be a possible cross-platform solution for you.  Perhaps this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930223/how-to-run-an-electron-app-on-docker

Comment: Thanks @Matt Morgan. Although I haven't given it quite a fair try, my understanding is docker no longer supports centos 6. I suppose I could use an old version of docker, but then would that old version be able to support Electron you think?

Comment: It's a fair question.  I don't know the answer, but maybe a little digging and experimentation will give you the answer.  It certainly sounds better than maintaining two different implementations.

Comment: I'm quickly gaining interest in this idea, but my only other reservation is that customers would be weary figuring out how to install docker on their machines. Is there a simplified way, maybe by distributing [docker binaries](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/)?

Comment: I would create a nodejs application that can be viewed from within the Browser. It can still access system resources then.

Comment: @HansKoch thank you, that idea intrigues me as well. The only two concerns then would be maintaining compatibility with old browsers and [protecting the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951302/node-js-code-protection), which appear to be the only downsides.

Comment: You can use the asar format outside of electron, which is the "protection" electron delivers i awnsered another question with in depth explaination about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033184/electronjs-code-protection-2018/50042857#50042857 For maintainability i would not be too concerned about it, browser and js specs are not changing drastically anymore. You can keep the nodejs version at a certain version too just keep in mind to use the recent LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://xpda.net offers a quick pros/cons list of alternative tools for Cross-Platform Desktop App (XPDA) development.